# Mapping Execution of Program

Tags: java

I am learning Java, and I was wondering whether there was some way of "mapping" the execution of a Java piece of code.

Ie:

Some kind of software which step by step executed the program and returned something like:

At line x this method is called and changed variable a from value b to value c.

etc.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can do step by step debugging using eclipse.

Here's a tutorial that shows you how:

http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/eclipse-debugger/